# angular: how to iterate over unlike objects and render different templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Say I have:

```
$scope.array = [{type: 'event'}, {type: 'alert'}];
```

How can I iterate over that and render a different item out of $templateCache for each, based on type.  We can assume 'event.html' and 'alert.html' exist.

Answer (score 3):

What other than Keegan's answer you can do is :

```
<div ng-repeat='a in array'>
    <div ng-include="a.type + '.html'"></div>
</div>
```

This way you get event.html or error.html loaded as per the value

Comment: Assuming the data is coming from an API, doesn't this imply that the server is now dictating which template to use?  Probably better if there was some intermediate mapping between type and the template.

Comment: I could not understand. Can you elaborate? Probably in the question only

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is the following.

```
<div ng-repeat='a in array'>
    <div ng-if="a.type =='event'">
        // EVENT.html TEMPLATE
    </div>

    <div ng-if="a.type == 'alert'">
       // ALERT.html TEMPLATE
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking for a solution that's less explicit and can easily be expanded to many types.